# VBA coeed in ms access to check if all forms are closed

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have MS access DB that includes several forms. The main form that works like main menu is 'F_StartUp'  which includes several buttons to activate other forms. When I open a form the 'F_StartUp' minimize. I need a VBA to check when I close all forms, if all forms are closed then maximize/open 'F_StartUp'. Below is what I have so far:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub openstartup()
    Dim frm As Object
    Dim isF_InPutOpen As Boolean
    Dim isF_CarriersOpen As Boolean
    Dim isF_InvOpen As Boolean
    Dim isF_QuoteOpen As Boolean

    ' Initialize variables to False
    isF_InPutOpen = False
    isF_CarriersOpen = False
    isF_InvOpen = False
    isF_QuoteOpen = False

    For Each frm In CurrentProject.AllForms
        If frm.IsLoaded Then
            If frm.Name = "F_InPut" Then
                isF_InPutOpen = True
            ElseIf frm.Name = "F_Carriers" Then
                isF_CarriersOpen = True
            ElseIf frm.Name = "F_Inv" Then
                isF_InvOpen = True
            ElseIf frm.Name = "F_Quote" Then
                isF_QuoteOpen = True
            End If
        End If
    Next frm

    ' Check the status of each form
    If isF_InPutOpen Then
        ' Code to be executed when F_InPut is open
    End If

    If isF_CarriersOpen Then
        ' Code to be executed when F_Carriers is open
    End If

    If isF_InvOpen Then
        ' Code to be executed when F_Inv is open
    End If
    '
    If isF_InvOpen Then
        ' Code to be executed when F_Quote is open
    End If
    'This will call macro module which will open 'F_StartUp'
    Call "workeddddd"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Application.Forms` collection contains all open forms.

```vb
If Application.Forms.Count = 2 Then
    DoCmd.Maximize ' Or DoCmd.Restore
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but Same issue , when I close a form , event if there is another form still open , it maximizes the 'F_StartUp'. in other words , it does the maximize with each closing. The maximize should happen only when all are closed.

Comment: If, besides F_Startup, there is yet another form open, then `Application.Forms.Count` will be greater than 1. Are you sure these other forms are really Forms and not say Reports or Tables or Queries?

Comment: Yes, I am sure all are forms .

Comment: Where is `Sub openstartup` called exactly? Can you put a breakpoint on `DoCmd.Maximize` and see which forms are open then?

Comment: So when I open a form the main menu form 'F_StartUp' is minimized, when I close a form its called. But If I have 2 or 3 forms open ,then, if I close one of them its should not call Sub openstartup unless I close all. What I am facing now that Sub openstartup is called every time I close a form even if  other forms are still open.

Comment: Where located sub ``openstartup`` and which event calls this sub? I think, when you close current form, will be activated another form - witch will active before. for example if sequence  ``form1_open->form2_open->form2_close`` causes ``form1_open`` by default.

Comment: The event call this sub is 'on close' ....                                                             Private Sub Form_Close()
Call openstartup
End Sub

Comment: It is okay for `openstartup` to be called every time a form is closed. It must contain the code I have shown instead of yours. The condition `If Application.Forms.Count = 1` makes sure `DoCmd.Maximize` is called only when exactly one form is remaining. Actually 2 Forms are still open then (I fixed the code): The closing one and the startup menu form.

Comment: I do appreciate all the help but I have no idea why its not working. I tried to put the code in Module or within 'F_StartUp' itself. Nothing is working .

Comment: Then you must [debug the VBA code](https://www.google.com/search?q=MS+Access+VBA+Debugging).

Comment: This code works perfectly to run msgbox when all closed but when I replace msgbox with 'DoCmd.Maximize' or 'DoCmd.Restore', nothing happens.                                                                        Public Sub openstartup()
If Application.Forms.Count = 2 Then MsgBox "worked"

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Thank you for everybodies help specially
Olivier Jacot

```
Public Sub openstartup()
If Application.Forms.Count = 2 Then DoCmd.OpenForm "F_StartUp"
'MsgBox "worked"

End Sub
```